# Can I save String into request attribute using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, request, attributes

Can I save String into HTTP request attribute using JavaScript? How?

Something like I do in JSP files:

```
request.setAttribute("sesion", "true");
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is `request`? Is that an XMLHttpRequest instance, or something else? Are you trying to set the property in a way that the server can read it?

Comment: It is HttpServletRequest request. I'm using it for send information between JSP and the ServletController

Comment: @DavidsZarzosoMoreno, CertainPerformance is commenting because they want to help you improve your question so that it can get a good answer and be beneficial to the community.  You should respond by editing your question to include the relevant details, not just by adding a comment.